# How can I know if a user of my Flask WebApp use a Windows or Linux machine?

Tags: python, flask, operating-system

Is there something in the request object for example that tells me what system the user uses ?

If I have a path from a file sent by the user, I want to be able to know (without a regex) if it's a Windows or LINUX PATH.

Is there an obvious way ?

Comment: You have to evaluate the `User-Agent` HTTP header.

Comment: Why would you care about the client path?

Comment: I tried os.path.basename() on a Windows path and it did not work, just found out about ntpath and it seems to work on both windows and linux path. I wanted to know the os of the user to be able to get the name of the file in both cases.

Comment: I wanted to get the name of the file. For Windows, I get C:\fake_path\fname. os.path.basename does not handle this. That's why I needed to be able to get the basename. I've found ntpath and it seems to work with Windows and Linux, so I don't have to check the user's platform. (But it's good to know how !)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get `User-Agent` header and parse it with [werkzeug.useragents.UserAgent](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/utils/#werkzeug.useragents.UserAgent)

```
from flask import request
from werkzeug.useragents import UserAgent

user_agent = UserAgent(request.headers.get('User-Agent'))
print(user_agent.platform)
```